# Django doesn't process POST request's payload from axios

Tags: reactjs, django, post, django-rest-framework, axios

I have React + Django REST Framework stack. DRF works as API and React as SPA. And I'm really confused why POST request doesn't work. If any additional information is required, please, ask me.

**In React**

I'm making POST request with axios like following:

```
axios
    .post(
        '/api/auth/register/',
        registrationInfo,
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
    )
    .then((response) => {
        setRegistrationStatus(response.data.status)
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
```

The frontend part of request seems to work fine. Payload and headers are shown: [image: payload], [image: headers]

**In DRF**
My serializer for registration look like this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(UserSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, write_only=True, required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, write_only=True, max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'created_at', 'modified_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=validated_data['email'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            return user
```

...and views:

```
class RegistrationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.query_params)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        res = {
                "refresh": str(refresh),
                "access": str(refresh.access_token),
                }
        return Response({
            "user": serializer.data,
            "refresh": res["refresh"],
            "token": res["access"]
            }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The output of DRF when making request is confusing. In developer tools-network the response is `{"email":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}`. And in console I have

```
Bad Request: /api/auth/register/
[15/Oct/2022 02:00:37] "POST /api/auth/register/ HTTP/1.1" 400 76
```

I'm not sure how payload works in POST requests, but managing payload in GET request with axios(which works for me) attaches payload to URL, whereas POST request's payload location is confusing. In postman the desired result is obtained. But it url-encodes payload: [image: POST request with postman]

Comment: The answer is the request payload was in self.request.data, not in self.request.query_params

Comment: i am so confused to how this answer helped when two months ago i got of gotten it in a request.POST but now its in request.data....... and im using vue.js but thanks it helped